# How to replace SELECTS in an Aggregate Function SUM()

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I create a workaround for a SELECT statement in a SUM-Function

I am currently migrating my Sybase Database towards MsSQL.
One of my Views has some SUMs in its main select statements which then use subSelects for a case in my SUM function

```
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN e.s = 'E'
                AND EXISTS 
                (   SELECT 
                        1 
                    FROM 
                        system.E
                        JOIN system.EF
                            ON EF.EID = E.ID
                    WHERE 
                        E.CID = C.ID 
                        AND EF.T='smth')
                        AND A.AC= 'smthelse' 
                        AND ET.EC not in( 'lol','lul','lel') 
            THEN 
                B.A
            ELSE
                0.0 
            END) AS smth
FROM ...
```

I expect it to SUM the b.A when the Select statement has at least 1 result

but instead I get this error message:

Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

I think it doesnt allow me to use a subSelect in the SUM-function, but im not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the subquery with a lateral `JOIN` by using the `OUTER APPLY` operator:

```
SELECT . . .
       SUM(CASE WHEN e.s = 'E' AND
                     eef.ID IS NOT NULL AND
                     A.AC = 'smthelse' AND
                     ET.EC NOT IN ( 'lol', 'lul', 'lel') 
                THEN B.A ELSE 0.0 
           END) AS smth
FROM ... OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) E.*
      FROM system.E JOIN
           system.EF
           ON EF.EID = E.ID
      WHERE E.CID = C.ID AND EF.T = 'smth'
     ) EEF
```

Comment: I see how u replace the subSelect, looks like a pretty solid solution.
But somehow im doin the OUTER APPLY wrong, it keeps telling me wrong syntax close to outer, with outer underlined. Can u explain how to properly use that?
Edit: I get a result by just adding your subquery to the from part without using outer apply but im not sure if thats the same :/

Comment: @Giga . . . I think there are many resources to explain the syntax and mechanism, such as https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-apply-basics/.  I don't think Sybase supports `APPLY`, but SQL Server does in all supported (and a few no longer supported) versions.

Comment: Thank you very much, i did figure it out :)